# BIOS detects a HHD but Windows doesn't

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I know there are several similar questions already, but this case is a little... special

I have 2 HHDs connected with SATA, one has Windows, and the other is just for backup.
Originally, the one had Windows was labeled as `C:`, and the other was `D:`.

One day, my Windows boot file have been corrupted, so I messed up with my disks...
During that, I noticed the two drives' labels was swapped, so I unplugged the backup drive and re-labeled the one that has Windows as `C:` again.

I successfully recovered the boot file, but after that, Windows fails to recognize the backup drive. It's not showing anywhere, such as disk manager, storage space, `diskpart / list disk`, etc. But the BIOS sees it.

I guess it's because I didn't label it from `C:` to another before unplugging it.
Could it be the reason? How can I fix it?

Comment: `C:` is reserved to the boot device. I don't know what you did, but whatever it was, better undo it.

Comment: A useful troubleshooting tool is Gparted live - https://gparted.org/livecd.php. Chuck it on a usb and use it to check the drive partition/s, SMART status, etc... Worst case, being a backup drive, you could blow it away and start afresh, right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem went away by itself after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clone the drives? It's possible that the drives have the same signature, and if that's the case, Windows will only recognize one drive. To fix that, normally you can go into [diskpart and check for unique device](https://www.howtohaven.com/system/change-disk-signature.shtml), however if it's not showing up in diskpart, or if you didn't clone the drive, either way, download [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.aomeitech.com/pa/standard.html) (free). Try to assign a drive letter there. It will at least tell you what it sees in the system. It's like diskpart on steroids. If it doesn't show the drive when you run the program, use it to make "bootable media" aka a bootable flash drive, then boot to that and check things out. If both drives don't show up in the bootable flash drive, then it's something more advanced, but we can cross that bridge if we come to it.

Labeling the disk does not matter to the system. You can label all drives the same label and they should all still show up. I'm thinking it's either a duplicate drive signature, or something else with the partitions. Either way, AOMEI PA or any other 3rd party partition software should give you more details and show what's going on.

If AOMEI PA doesn't even see the drive... is the drive plugged in via SATA, or is there a RAID controller, etc? Make sure your chipset software & drivers are up-to-date so that everything detects as it should. Microsoft has been doing a lot of changes lately with Windows and some of the changes can break things. I had to reinstall my SATA drivers the other day after the latest Windows update.

If still no luck, feel free to comment and I'll help.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, the software you mentioned didn't work either, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

After several reboots, at some point it was being correctly detected as D: again now... I don't know why but I guess I'll take it